# Visualizing conformal map from unit disk to upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I understand that
$$w=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$$
maps the open upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ to the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, so
$$z=i\frac{1+w}{1-w}$$
maps from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{H}$. My question is how? Are there any good GIFs or visuals that could show which points map to where?

I am asking because ultimately I want to determine how the right half unit disk would map using this same map.

Comment: This is the Cayley transform, a good visualization can be found on its respective wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform

Comment: The wikipedia page on the Cayley transform has a nice picture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been looking for any GIF which illustrates this transformation, but haven't found any... So I decided to create my own. I made [this GIF](https://i.imgur.com/nlDfUhQ.mp4) with a little python code. I have uploaded this code I just made [here](https://github.com/ArrozConTomate/gif_maker). I hope you like it!

Comment: This is spectacular thank you!

Comment: You can see clearly how the right half-plane gets mapped to the lower half-disc, and how the conformal mapping transforms the original orthogonal cartesian coordinates into a different set of orthogonal coordinates. I´m glad you liked it!